# Apache Reverse Proxy Issue

Tags: apache, proxy

I am trying to user mod_proxy to set up the reverse proxy for multiple web application using a single Apache web server (version 2.4).

I have two applications running on two different tomcat servers:

```
1. http://app.test.com:8080/app
2. http://app.test.com:8090/app
```

I have enabled the required modules in the httpd.conf file and added the below lines to the same:

```
> ProxyPass /App1/ http://app.test.com:8080/app
> ProxyPassReverse /App2/ http://app.test.com:8090/app
```

The issue is when I test this using below URL

> `http://rp.test.com:80/App1/ and http://rp.test.com:80/App2/`,the apache webserver does send me to the apps hosted on tomcats but gives a 404 error on clicking any internal link of the application.

Think I am missing some configuration part here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to configure Tomcat connectors behind the proxy. Somethink like this, containing your external server name and port.

```
<Connector port="8081" ...
          proxyName="www.mycompany.com"
          proxyPort="80"/>
```

To adjust the path in the URL, you may use the proxypassreversepath directive, see:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiepath

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /App1/ /app/
```

Comment: Tried above fix. The problem what I am facing is when I go to the page using : http://rp.test.com:80/App1/ and click a link it gets automatically resolved to http://rp.test.com:80/manager.html and throws 404 error. Actual url must be http://rp.test.com:80/App1/manager.html